# How can I load a large dataset into memory on ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Context:

- I am building an API to support a search query suggestion feature.

  - For example, a GET request to "/api/values/micro" will return suggestions such as "microwave", "micromanager", etc..
- I am using ASP.NET Core to construct this API (hosted on Azure).
- I am going to use a trie data structure to quickly fetch search results.
- I have a file with about 7 million lines of data. Each line is the title of a wikipedia article.
- I am going to seed this trie with data from this file.
- Instead of embedding this data file into my Visual Studio project and deploying it to Azure, I want to upload this data file to Azure blob storage.
- At initialization time, I need my ASP.NET Core API to fetch this file from blob storage and load it into memory as a trie so that subsequent HTTP requests can retrieve data from this trie quickly (makes no sense to do this for each request).

Question:

How can I load this data at initialization time, before HTTP requests start coming in? Do I do it in my controller's constructor? In my Startup.cs? I would appreciate some guidance here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that this data is loaded before calling any code in your controllers, then you could put it in the `Startup` class which is used for bootstrapping your application.

Comment: Should I put it in the constructor? Or in one of the ConfigureServices() or Configure() methods?

Comment: You could put it in the `Configure` method.

Comment: I see. If I fetch this data in my Startup.Configure() method and store it as a dictionary, how can I pass that dictionary to my Controller's methods?

Comment: You could just inject it as some sort of a dependency object to your controllers. Just register it as a singleton object in your dependency injection framework and have your controllers take it as constructor dependency.

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot of sense after reading up about those things. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in `Configure` method. Code should be something like this, then webapp will be available until data are pre-loaded.

```
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            //service should has been configured in ConfigureServices step
            //Create method to check if data loaded. If not then load them.
            serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>().CheckDataLoaded();
        }
        //more steps here..
```

Comment: Could you explain what the serviceScope is, and what this checkDataLoaded() method does? I didn't really understand what is going on in this code that you wrote. My default template code does not include that.

Comment: Also if I fetch this data in my Startup.Configure() method and store it as a dictionary, how can I pass that dictionary to my Controller's methods?